# inserting an image file in system documents directory in corona

Tags: image, coronasdk

I am new to corona and I am trying to take multiple pictures from iphone camera and trying to insert these in `system.douments.directory` .Can someone here help me how to insert a new image file with a unique name in this directory.
and what if I want to customize the location where to save the image??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do this by using this following snippet

```
local dateTime = os.date("%c" )
display.save(imageCaptured,tostring(dateTime)..".jpg")
```

dateTime always give me a new name and `imageCaptured` is the image I have taken from camera api.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, you can't.

Corona as a rule can only save on the application sandbox.

For images, you can save to the library using this:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/capture.html